# Sync Imessage Group Chat History between devices

Tags: macos, iphone, messages, data-synchronization, messages-in-icloud

I accidentally deleted the history of an imessage groupchat from my iphone but it still appears on my mac. Is there any way I can use this to recover it on my phone? They sync through iCloud.

I've backed up the folder `~/Library/Messages`. How do I use those .ichat files to restore the chat in my iPhone?

Comment: better to disconnect Mac from internet and then try to figure out the solution, or they'd disappear from Mac too. All the transcript is stored in `~/Library/Messages`

Comment: @ankii on your advice I've backed up that folder. I presume that could lead to problems if I try to merge a future version with the backup. Though, if I have to lose them I lose them and I can't afford to go internet silent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that I did a long time ago which you can try at your own risk. First make a backup of the following folder, maybe in a removable device to be on the safe side.

**What you need:**

- Backup the following files from your user folder. Don't delete any folder beside instructed one. Library is hidden so press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to make them visible. Use same button to revert it back

  *~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat*

  *~/Library/Message*

  *~/Library/Preferences -> Find all the files that contain the string "iChat" or 
  "iMessage"*

Note: Kindly do this without being on the Internet from the start else iCloud from iPhone can sync with your MacBook later and you might get an issue.

Now as a crucial step:

- Rename

*~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat*  -> *~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat_old*

*~/Library/Message* -> *~/Library/Message_old*

**But, Find all the files in** *~/Library/Preferences* that contain the string "**iChat**" or "**iMessage**" and *CUT* them into a separate folder or external HDD. Be sure to remember where you copied them from! **Don't rename this folder or files under it**.

After this, copy all the original folder that you have backed up

**For example:**

*com.apple.iChat* -> to the original place under *~/Library/Containers* so here you will have two file *com.apple.iChat_old* and *com.apple.iChat*

The same goes for the message folder. However, you have cut, so paste back the file that contains iChat and iMessage back to the Preferences.

**DO NOT START THE MESSAGES APP and restart your computer**

Open Messages, your old chats should all be there. And sync with your iCloud from Mac and it should come to your iPhone also.

Comment: Wow, workarounds are always surprising! this must have been tough to figure out.. You could also give it a read again and see if steps can be clarified further..